# How to get Id's of field in Javascript where fields are displayed through apex:repeat tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community

In Apex page I'm having 2 address sections i.e., Current Address and Permanent address but these address fields are placed in Custom setting and displaying through apex:repeat tag in page.We have a one check Permanent address is same as Current Address.When I click on that check box I need to copy current address in permanent address using Java Script but I'm not able to get Id's of the fields.Can any one provide the solution how to get the Id's field in JavaScript.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although finding elements by ID is the first approach to consider, it is also possible to find elements by other attributes including their CSS class. You can add a class (that has no associated styling), and use the class names to find the elements.

For your situation where the field names are coming from a custom setting, using the class names to do the matching works well because you can just use the field name as the class name. (Visualforce does not allow ID values to be expressions.) Adding jQuery into the mix ensures that the code works well across multiple browsers.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class MyController {
    public String[] fromFields {
        get {
            return new String[] {'BillingStreet', 'BillingState'};
        }
    }
    public String[] toFields {
        get {
            return new String[] {'ShippingStreet', 'ShippingState'};
        }
    }
    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        String[] fields = new String[] {};
        fields.addAll(fromFields);
        fields.addAll(toFields);
        sc.addFields(fields);
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:outputLink styleClass="copyLink">Copy</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:repeat value="{!fromFields}" var ="f">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account[f]}" styleClass="{!f}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
                <apex:repeat value="{!toFields}" var ="f">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Account[f]}" styleClass="{!f}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
<apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"/>
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
   j$('.copyLink').click(function(e) {
       var fromFields = [<apex:repeat value="{!fromFields}" var ="f">'{!f}',</apex:repeat>];
       var toFields = [<apex:repeat value="{!toFields}" var ="f">'{!f}',</apex:repeat>];
       for (var i = 0; i < fromFields.length; i++) {
           j$('.' + toFields[i]).val(j$('.' + fromFields[i]).val());
       }
       e.preventDefault();
   });
});
</script>
</apex:page>
```

**PS**

This is one way of having a named function that you can also invoke in `oncomplete`:

```
<apex:actionSupport ... oncomplete="addClick()"/>

...

<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var addClick = function() {
   j$('.copyLink').click(function(e) {
       var fromFields = [<apex:repeat value="{!fromFields}" var ="f">'{!f}',</apex:repeat>];
       var toFields = [<apex:repeat value="{!toFields}" var ="f">'{!f}',</apex:repeat>];
       for (var i = 0; i < fromFields.length; i++) {
           j$('.' + toFields[i]).val(j$('.' + fromFields[i]).val());
       }
       e.preventDefault();
   });
};
j$(document).ready(addClick);
</script>
```

Comment: How to use checkbox instead of output link to copy address

Comment: @Bujji For a checkbox replace `click` with `change` and remove the `e.preventDefault();`. But what does the checkbox being checked or unchecked mean in that case?

Comment: It's working fine when the initialy vf page is loaded but when we rerender any part of the page then it's not working.can you provide any suggestions.

Comment: @Bujji Your `j$(document).ready` will attach the logic when the page is first loaded but if you re-load the section the logic is not re-attached by default. If you are using `apex:actionfunction`, that can have `oncomplete` JavaScript, and if you make your current `j$(document).ready` function a named function you can call that from both `j$(document).ready` and `oncomplete`. (That does work, but in general I try to use either jQuery or partial page refreshes but not both to keep things simpler.)

Comment: I'm not using apex:actionfunction just i'm using apex:actionsupport to call controller method using onchange event.How to create a J$(document).ready as a named function any example

Comment: @Bujji See the PS I've added to the answer. Please no more questions here - good luck.

Comment: Thanks Keith,Suppose if I'm using 10 apex:actionsupport functions to rerender my sections in a page then i need to attach this oncomplete method to each and every apex:actionsupport tag in my page.

Comment: ,This JQuery logic is not working in IE8.You have any suggestions.

Comment: @Bujji ... only that you will have to debug that (unless you get lucky Googling). Not sure how good IE8's debug tools are but there should be a JavaScript console available where you can output debug information. The problem might be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie.

Comment: ,In my Scenario I'm not using event.preventDefault(); because I'm using checkbox not the link .

Answer (score 1):

In visualforce when you create an element like  Salesforce well add a prefix for the DOM element Id
So to get the exact DOM element Id you have to use **$Component.myInputField**

Code example :

```
<script>
 var jsId = [];
 // then in your JS function you could do something like this :
 document.getElementById(jsId["myInputField"]).value = "new val"; 
</script>

<apex:outputPanel >
  <apex:inputField value="{!MyObject__c.MyField__c}" id="myInputField"/>
  <script>jsId["myInputField"] = "{!$Component.myInputField}";</script>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

For more info [official visualforce documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm)