# How get the date field id using javascript in vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, community, dynamic-visualforce

Hi i am trying to get the date field id using javascript in vf page. This Date field is rendered based on meeting type picklist. I tried so many ways but it won't work. my requirement is If Date field is empty it will show the error message. I am tried like

```
document.getElementById('thepage:fname:pb:pbs:pbsMeetingDate:meetingDate').value;
```

and using component also tried but it won't work. 
Date field code is

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pbsMeetingDate">
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Meeting Date" rendered="{!If(action.Meeting_Type__c!=null,true,false)}"></apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:outputPanel layout="block">
                        <div class="requiredInput">
                            <div class="requiredBlock" id="meetDate"  ></div>
                            <apex:inputField value="{!action.Meeting_Date__c}"  id="meetingDate" rendered="{!If(action.Meeting_Type__c!=null,true,false)}"/>                       
                            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="display:none;" styleclass="errorMsg" id="validMeetingDate">
                                <strong>Error:</strong> Enter Meeting Date 
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>                
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Id's of field in Javascript where fields are displayed through apex:repeat tag](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33754/how-to-get-ids-of-field-in-javascript-where-fields-are-displayed-through-apexr)

Comment: Have you tried using $Component. Please refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_component.htm) for details. Hope this will help.

Comment: I think it's different enough - it looks like the answer to this requires some test as to whether the date field exists, as well as the content.